# how to crop a video in bootstrap carousel

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having an issue with placing a HTML5 video in a bootstrap carousel. 
My carousel is supposed to take up 90% of the screen so that it is responsive.

I am trying to place a video in carousel with a width of roughly 200% (H x W) of its size, so that i can use a div to crop it with `overflow hidden` to 90% of the screen.

But my div shows the whole video, and its not responsive. I can figure out why.

**HTML**

```
<!-- Carousel.
    ================================================== -->
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" style="background: none;">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner ">
            <div class="item active">
            <div class="croppedvideo">
                <video class="videoInsert" autoplay loop poster="~/Content/video/posters/b-roll-1.jpg" muted>
                    <source src="https://broken-links.com/tests/media/BigBuck.webm" type="video/webm">
                    <source src="https://broken-links.com/tests/media/BigBuck.m4v" type="video/mp4" />
                    Your browser does not support the video tag.
                </video>
            </div>
            </div>



        </div>
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
    </div>
    <!-- /.carousel -->
```

**CSS**

```
#myCarousel {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.videoInsert {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    right: 0; 
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    min-width: 100%; 
    min-height: 100%;
    width:200%;
    height: 200%; 
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1000;
}
.croppedvideo{
  width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
    overflow: hidden
}
.item {
  height: inherit;
}
```

here is my jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/neosketo/3odjmxd1/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to get the carousel to be 90% of the *height* of the page, I don't see that applied anywhere. You're applying a 90% height to the cropped video div, you'll want to apply this to your actual carousel. You'll also need to apply a height to the `<body>` and `<html>` tags so that the 90% is based off of the full page height.

See an updated fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/6cgm8ybq/1/

These are the changes I made:

```
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}
#myCarousel {
  height: 90%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.croppedvideo{
  width: 100%;
  /* height: 90%; */
  /* overflow: hidden */
}
```